# "Titan Dahl's hedge fund's website" vs. "Titan Dahl hedge fund's website"

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

1. Titan Dahl's hedge fund's website" 
   or
2. Titan Dahl hedge fund's website

Methinks the second is correct. I need to know which of the sentences above is correct as I add plenty of references to an online encyclopedia. In this case, it's the website that belongs to a hedge fund that belongs to Titan Dahl that is being referenced.

Comment: Between the *two*, the first is correct: it's the website that belongs to a hedge fund that belongs to Titan Dahl. However, depending on what is actually meant to be expressed, it could also be (and would seem more natural to me to be) *Titan Dahl's hedge-fund website.* In other words, the *hedge-fund website that belongs to Titan Dhal*. What is it that is actually being referenced?

Comment: @Jason Bassford : In this case, it's the website that belongs to a hedge fund that belongs to Titan Dahl that is being referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem having as many possessives as are required to describe a situation.

From the question:

> In this case, it's the website that belongs to a hedge fund that belongs to Titan Dahl that is being referenced.

So, in reverse order:

1. A hedge fund that belongs to Titan Dhal: *Titan Dahl's hedge fund.*
2. The website that belongs to a hedge fund: *Hedge fund's website.*

Putting that together:

> Titan Dahl's hedge fund's website.

This matches the first sentence in the question, making it the more accurate description.